# Copying a subset of the arguments object, without using an explicit loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I have a JavaScript function that takes two required parameters and then arbitrarily many optional parameters.

```
function myFunction(required1, required2) {
    var more = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; ++i)
        more.push(arguments[i]);
    // ...
}
```

Now, I like enforcing a consistent style through all my code. Since my site uses jQuery, and jQuery favors using `$.each` and `$.map` over explicit loops, I want to get rid of the explicit loop in `myFunction`. However, I cannot use either `$.each` or `$.map` because I don't want to copy the whole argument list, lest I do the following:

```
var more = $.map(arguments, function(argument, index) {
    return (index < 2) ? null : [argument];
});
```

Which is, of course, a very bad idea, because testing whether `index < 2` in every iteration is unnecessary.

I would really like to be able to extract a subset of the `arguments` object into a new array, using a standard function. However, because `arguments` is not an array, I cannot `slice` it.

Is there any other way I could extract into an array all arguments but the two first ones, without using an explicit loop, and without losing efficiency?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method:

```
var optional_arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

We have to call it from `Array.prototype` because, even though `arguments` is array-like, it doesn't actually have a `slice` method.

Comment: I suppose a slightly more succinct syntax would be `[].slice.call(...)`

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call` is slightly more efficient (and conceptually way more accurate), because I don't need to create an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of a function can be treated like an array with jQuery, for instance the following works perfectly fine:

```
function something(ar1,ar2){
    var args = $(arguments).slice(2);
    $(args).each(function(i){
        $('#stuff').append(args[i]+'<br />');
    });
}
$(function(){
    something('one','two','three','four');
});
```

And to tailor it to your function above it would look like this:

```
function myFunction(required1, required2) {
    var more = [];
    var args = $(arguments).slice(2);
    $(args).each(function(i){
        more.push(args[i]);
    });
}
```

Comment: No, the `arguments` object is not an array. It is array-like, but not an actual `Array`.

Comment: @Tim Down Ah yes you're correct, sorry I'm too used to jQuery doing things for me now.